# Kotlin: scheduling an activity as a service

Tags: android, kotlin, scheduledexecutorservice

I'm new to Android development.
After a month looking here and there on Internet I succeeded in developing an app that is able to call a runnable class (ScheduledTests in the code below) every x seconds with:

```
private var startTests = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor()
val st = ScheduledTests()
testProvider = startTests.scheduleAtFixedRate(st, 1, 5, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
```

The problem is that the runnable is called only if the app is active. If I active another app or if the phone goes stand by the function isn't called anymore.

I guess I have to configure a service but I don't know how.
Is there a document with examples I can read?

Comment: Read the documentation on the Android Developer site about WorkManager.

Comment: Doing something every 5 seconds indefinitely is bad for the battery. Users yelled very loudly about apps like yours doing things like this. As a result, Google and device manufacturers go to great lengths to prevent you from doing things like this. I recommend that you read [the documentation](https://developer.android.com/develop/background-work/background-tasks) on background work, learn more about `WorkManager`, and revise your plans so that you can do this work much less frequently.

Comment: Thanks! 5 seconds is just to test the app, and that is an app specifically developed to make tests, not for everybody